# View Controller crashes when Core Data object is created

Tags: ios, core-data, uipickerview

I have a view controller that is triggered when a user asks to add an object to a database.  The view has text input fields as well as a UIPICKERVIEW.  The view loads and works fine until I add an NSMANAGEDOBJECT to store the inputted data.

The header file:

```
    `@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;`

    `@property (strong, nonatomic) Training *trainingEvent;`
    `@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *eventTypes;`
```

and the .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.typePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];

if (self.managedObjectContext) {
    NSLog(@"managed object context loaded");
} else {
    NSLog(@"no managed object context loaded");
}

NSLog(@"event types loaded :%lu", (long unsigned)self.eventTypes.count);

if (self.trainingEvent) {
    NSLog(@"training event loaded %@", self.trainingEvent.name);
} else {
    //create new event in MOC
    NSLog(@"create new training event");
    NSEntityDescription *trainingEntityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Training"
                                                                 inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    Training *newTrainingEvent = (Training *)[[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:trainingEntityDescription
                                                 insertIntoManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    self.trainingEvent = newTrainingEvent;



}
}
```

when I comment out the else clause, (create new event in MOC)
the view works fine.  but as written I get the following error:

```
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`
```

attached UIPICKER methods:

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

//cell.textLabel.text = [arrWebServiceList count] > 0 ? [arrWebServiceList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] : @"DummyText";
NSLog(@"titleForRow %lu", (long)row);
return [self.eventTypes objectAtIndex:row];
}

-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row     forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *tView = (UILabel *)view;
NSLog(@"viewForRow %lu", (long)row);
if (!tView) {
    tView = [[UILabel alloc] init];


    tView.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
    [tView setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0]];
    tView.numberOfLines = 4;
    tView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
}

tView.text = [self.eventTypes objectAtIndex:row];


return tView;
}
```

Question:  how can I create a core data object to store the data?

Comment: In what way does that `else` clause not work? You said what happens when you comment it out, but what about when you leave it in?

Comment: When I leave it in, the app crashes with the error `index 0 beyond bounds of an empty array.` the only array is self.eventTypes and I know it is not empty at the end of viewDidLoad.

Comment: How do you know it's not empty? Where do you assign something to it?

Comment: before leaving viewDidLoad I log self.eventType.count and get 21 objects.  That array is loaded by the previous view in the prepareForSegue.  Also, when I comment out that else clause, the array is fully populated

Comment: After working on it all day, the array it is looking at is the array of core data objects which is empty because I haven't saved any yet.  I don't see where it is looking at that array.

Comment: Do you have an NSFetchedResultsController?  If so, that could be the source of the problem - particularly if you are using a cache.

Comment: I do use a fetched results controller.  I think I have found the problem.  My fetched results controller is feeding an NSArray.  so when I add an object to the store, the array doesnt contain it and throws the exception.  I took out that array and store the fetched results directly.